# how to Enabled only one column value

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have kendoGrid with 21 rows and 8 columns.i have set particular rows background color as well as hidden those rows values.for that purpose i have written these two lines of code

```
$("#grid1 tbody").find("tr:eq(0), tr:eq(2), tr:eq(11),tr:eq(15)")
    .addClass('rowColor');

$("#grid2 tbody").find("tr:eq(0), tr:eq(2), tr:eq(11), tr:eq(15)")
    .find("td").html("");
```

now i want to display hidden first row,third row,16 th row first column value...how can i do this ..make sure values are coming from database...

Comment: do u use this code  " $("#grid2 tbody").find("tr:eq(0), tr:eq(2), tr:eq(11), tr:eq(15)")
    .find("td").html("");" to hide the row ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First , If you want to hide a row you can use `.hide()`

```
$("#grid2 tbody").find("tr:eq(0), tr:eq(2), tr:eq(11), tr:eq(15)")
.find("td").hide();
```

not

```
$("#grid2 tbody").find("tr:eq(0), tr:eq(2), tr:eq(11), tr:eq(15)")
.find("td").html("");
```

because `.html("")` will actually empty its content not just hide

then to show first column only use :

```
$("#grid2 tbody").find("tr:eq(0), tr:eq(2), tr:eq(11), tr:eq(15)").find("td:first").show();
```